# VBA code lower case to upper case using Mid string

Tags: vba, uppercase, lowercase

I've gotten stuck with this VBA code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to change the first letters of 2 words from lower case to upper case. Also, how should I take the space in between these two words into consideration in the code?

I haven't been able to execute the code as I keep getting this compile error: "Argument not optional".

```
Function Properword(Text)
Dim rText
rText = Len(rText)
If rText(Mid(1, 1)) = LCase(Str) Then
    rText = UCase(Str)
    If rText(Mid(6, 1)) = LCase(Str) Then
    rText = UCase
End If
```

End Function

Cheers!

Comment: show an example of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Have rolled-back.  Remember not to remove the question when thanking people, makes the answers hard to understand. :)  Just tick the answer that you consider answered the question.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you don't have to use UDF. Simply use inbuilt `WorksheetFunction.Proper` function to achieve ProperCase.

If you still want to create UDF, an example would be

```
Function Properword(strTxt)
    Dim arrTxt

    arrTxt = Split(strTxt, " ")
    For i = LBound(arrTxt) To UBound(arrTxt)
        arrTxt(i) = UCase(Left(arrTxt(i), 1)) & Mid(arrTxt(i), 2)
    Next

    Properword = Join(arrTxt, " ")
End Function
```

Finally, issues with your code

`rText = Len(rText)` ~~ this means rText will contain a numeric value because `Len` returns the lenght of the string

`If rText(Mid(1, 1)) = LCase(Str) Then` ~~ `Mid` takes the string as first argument followed by start point and then end point (optional).

not sure what you were trying to do in the following lines.

```
rText = UCase(Str)
If rText(Mid(6, 1)) = LCase(Str) Then
rText = UCase
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Excel function `PROPER`

```
str = WorksheetFunction.Proper("UPPER lower")   ' "Upper Lower"
```

There is also the `VBA.StrConv` function:

```
str = StrConv("UPPER lower", vbProperCase)      ' "Upper Lower"
```

---

To convert only parts of the string to uppercase, you can use [`RegEx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops), or the [Mid statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz5s6003):

```
Mid(str, 1, 1) = UCase(Mid(str, 1, 1))          ' makes the first letter uppercase
```